# How can I optionally pluralize the word "diagnosis" in writing?

Tags: grammatical-number, parentheses, parenthetical-plural

I'm building a web form and am looking to label a check box list used to select one or more diagnoses.  I want to label this list in a way that indicates to the user that they may select one or more items.

If it were a list of cars, the label would read "Car(s)".  The 's' in parentheses indicates that they may select multiple cars but it's not necessary.

How would I do the same for the word diagnosis?  My first thought was "Diagnosis(es)".  Is this correct?

Comment: @Bogdan - Correct. However, I'm looking to write the word in a way that conveys that both the singular and plural form may apply.

Comment: You can't go wrong with Diagnosis/Diagnoses.

Comment: "Diagnosis(es)" is certainly awkward. For me, just "Diagnoses" is a little awkward too, especially if the usual case will be a single diagnosis. I would probably just write "Diagnosis" and in smaller letters "(check all that apply)".

Comment: @Jason - I like it.  I think I'll go with that.  If this were UX I'd say you should post it as an answer.  I am still curious about the the correctness of diagnosis(es) though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that Diagnosis(es) is awkward...I would suggest using the form that represents the most common usage: "Diagnoses" if there are usually multiple diagnoses, and "Diagnosis" if one diagnosis is the norm.

Comment: When speaking, the plural Diagnoses is usually pronounced `Di-ag-no-sees`, while the verb Diagnoses is pronounced `Di-ag-no-sez`